# Changing multiple columns name, pasting at the beginning/end of column name

Tags: r, multiple-columns

I have a very easy question but I am a bit struggling with it as I am not good with string manipulation,
I have a dataset that looks something like this

```
df <- data.frame(id= c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), time=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3),y = rnorm(9), x1 = rnorm(9), x2 = c(0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1),c2 = rnorm(9))
df
#    id  time    y         x1      x2     c2
# 1  1    1  0.2849573 -2.0675484  0  -0.07262881
# 2  1    2  0.7790181 -0.7575962  0  -0.58792408
# 3  1    3  1.5612293  0.6249859  0   1.19410761
# 4  2    1  0.5001897  3.4156129  0  -0.03577452
# 5  2    2  0.7155184 -0.5672982  1  -1.22208675
# 6  2    3  0.5086272 -0.7848763  0  -0.41084467
# 7  3    1 -0.4707959  0.1159467  1   0.77233201
# 8  3    2  0.8641184  0.2498162  1   0.49336869
# 9  3    3  1.3348043 -0.6803672  1  -0.33189217
```

I would simply like to change all the column names from x1 onwards adding a "_0". the final dataset should look like this.

```
final
#   id   time     y       x1_o     x2_o    c2_o
# 1  1    1  1.1251762 -0.7191008    0  -0.07478527
# 2  1    2  0.7585758  1.8694635    0  -0.42652822
# 3  1    3 -1.3180201 -0.4336776    0   0.38417779
# 4  2    1  1.7335904  2.2968254    0  -0.35639828
# 5  2    2  0.1506950 -0.5481873    1  -0.38523601
# 6  2    3 -1.9475207 -0.5302951    0   0.21721675
# 7  3    1 -0.1024133 -0.2872962    1  -0.06347213
# 8  3    2  0.1316069  0.1463118    1  -0.19518602
# 9  3    3 -1.1037682 -0.1129085    1  -0.24011278
```

I am able to change column names one by one, but I would like to find a one-liner command. 
I have tried this, but it is only able to paste at the beginning.

```
dp_o<-df %>% rename_at(3:5, ~paste("_o",.))
```

Probably it is just a variation of the code above, but I am struggling a bit to understand which variation given that I do not understand well string manipulation

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need the `_o` at the end as `paste` concatenates based on arguments from left to right and not the reverse

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    rename_at(3:5, ~ paste0(., "_o"))
#   id time         y_o        x1_o x2_o         c2
#1  1    1  0.62714872 -0.70259726    0  0.4386072
#2  1    2 -0.53052052 -0.37854004    0  1.8857944
#3  1    3 -0.97729791  0.70909984    0  0.3611839
#4  2    1 -0.31016711 -1.12787900    0  0.9684549
#5  2    2 -1.91335148 -1.84690443    1 -0.1196826
#6  2    3 -0.03967186  0.21916880    0  0.6295054
#7  3    1  1.18847857 -0.75449457    1 -1.4622606
#8  3    2  0.81352527 -0.44126036    1  0.8604688
#9  3    3  1.92443154 -0.04599181    1 -0.9240210
```

Or if we need to match the column name

```
df %>%
   rename_at(vars(match('x1', names(.)):ncol(.)), ~ paste0(., '_o'))
```

Or with `str_c`

```
library(stringr)
df %>%
    rename_at(vars(x1:c2), ~ str_c(., '_o'))
```

Comment: Great exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using the `data.table` package, the following would work

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)
old <- colnames(df)[c(which(colnames(df)=="x1"):length(colnames(df)))]
new <- paste(old, "0", sep="_")
setnames(df, old, new)
df[]
##    id time          y       x1_0 x2_0        c2_0
##  1  1    1 -1.5612344  0.9711583    0 -1.08198269
##  2  1    2  0.8090729 -0.9474716    0 -0.21020803
##  3  1    3  0.8070253  0.9765167    0  2.13507943
##  4  2    1  0.7446732 -0.2459540    0  0.64870743
##  5  2    2 -1.1853776 -0.3828339    1 -0.09298909
##  6  2    3  0.5057534  0.5822639    0  0.79730587
##  7  3    1 -0.3655794 -0.1628970    1 -0.57866153
##  8  3    2 -1.3465086  1.1107107    1  1.11290979
##  9  3    3 -0.8271092 -0.4105378    1  0.88522610
```

Comment: Thanks this works indeed. I was wondering whether there is a way to do it as a one-liner command

Answer (score 1):

With `base R`, maybe you can make it via the following code:

```
names(df)[-(1:3)] <- paste0(names(df)[-(1:3)],"_o")
```

which gives:

```
> df
  id time          y        x1_o x2_o       c2_o
1  1    1 -1.1861828 -0.97027842    0  1.8556257
2  1    2  1.1964478  0.48936940    0 -0.2144602
3  1    3 -1.1164802  0.03258791    0 -1.7737551
4  2    1  0.4940969 -1.31300219    0  0.1865097
5  2    2 -0.8735071 -1.01195060    1  0.6515702
6  2    3  0.1749421  0.27409115    0 -1.2432389
7  3    1  1.8849013  0.92642054    1  0.9861089
8  3    2 -0.3765072 -1.15343868    1  0.8451167
9  3    3 -0.2033892  1.66717960    1 -0.1480590
```